# $\det(N) = \det(Q^{-1} B Q) = \det(Q^{-1}) \det(B) \det(Q) = \det(B) = -5 $

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let the matrix $B$ of order $3$ with $\det(B) = -5$.

Let $Q$ the orthogonal matrix  of order $3$ and $N$ a matrix of order $3$ such that $B = Q N Q^t$. What is the determinant of $N$.

I am not sure I am on the right track. $N = Q^t B Q = Q^{-1} B Q$. $\det(N) = \det(Q^{-1} B Q) = \det(Q^{-1}) \det(B) \det(Q) = \det(B) = -5 $. Am I right to say that?

Comment: $\det (Q^{-1})\det( B)\det (Q)=\det(Q^{-1})\det (Q)\det( B)=\det(Q^{-1}Q)\det (B)=\det(I)\det (B)=\det( B)$

Comment: @Robert I'll say you are right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, and you're right,

but perhaps you should show more details to be convincing.

Matrix multiplication is not commutative, but multiplication of determinants is commutative.

Thus, $\det (N)=\det(Q^{-1}BQ)=\det (Q^{-1})\det( B)\det (Q)=\det(Q^{-1})\det (Q)\det( B)$

$=\det(Q^{-1}Q)\det (B)=\det(I)\det (B)=1\times\det( B)=\det(B).$